# accessing object values using variable as a key

Tags: dart

I'm trying to access a class value by using a variable previously defined in dart, but I keep getting the error `the operator [] isn't defined for the class`

In Javascript I would access an object value using a variable like this:

```
let movie = {
  movieTitle : 'Toy Story',
  actor: 'Tom Hanks'
}

let actorName = 'actor';
console.log(movie[actorName]); // <- what I'm trying to replicate in dart
// expected output: Tom Hanks
```

Here is what I've tried and is throwing that error

```dart
class Movie {
  String name;
  String actor;
  String producer;
}

void main() {
  var movieTitle = new Movie();
  movieTitle.name = 'Toy Story';
  movieTitle.actor = 'Tom Hanks';

  print(movieTitle.actor); <- prints out Tom Hanks as expected

  var actorName = 'actor';

  print(movieTitle[actorName]); <- throws error
}
```

I expect to be able to use a variable on the fly to access the value.

A trivial use case for me would be if I had a a list of Movie classes, where some actors and producers are null, I would like to filter on either non null actors or producer with a function like so:

```
List values = movieList.where((i) => i.actor != "null").toList(); // returns all Movies in movieList where the actor value isn't the string "null"

var actorIsNull = 'actor';

List values = movieList.where((i) => i[actorisNull] != "null").toList(); // throws error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot access class members by a string containing their name. (Except with mirrors - outside the scope of this answer.)

You could remove the class altogether and just use a `Map<String, String>`.

```
Map<String, String> movie = {
  'movieTitle': 'Toy Story',
  'actor': 'Tom Hanks',
}
```

You could add some `bool` methods on the class.

```
bool hasNoActor() => actor == null;
...
List values = movieList.where((m) => !m.hasNoActor()).toList();
```

Or, you could pass a lambda to your mapper.

```
  Movie movieTitle = Movie()
    ..name = 'Toy Story'
    ..actor = 'Tom Hanks';

  Function hasActor = (Movie m) => m.actor != null;
  List values = movieList.where(hasActor).toList();
```

Answer (score 10):

You can createn a `toMap()` function in your Movie class and access properties using `[] operator`

```
class Movie {
  String name;
  String actor;
  String producer;

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'actor' : actor,
      'producer' : producer,
    };
  }
}
```

Now Movie class properties can be accessed as:

```
Movie movie = Movie();
movie.toMap()['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem, and although in your case a Map will go around it, to generalize to any Object, you can either look into the mirror package or other similar package, or this:

I made a `getAny` function for my object, which takes in a String and returns one of its variables depending on the value of the String (in a switch case statement); this works for any attribute if you make the function of the dynamic type. It's something like this:

```dart
dynamic getAny(String field){
  switch(field):
    case("name"):
      // doesn't need this.name as this function is inside the object
      return name;
    case("actor"):
      return actor;
    default:
      // treat here as you like, you can throw an Exception or return null, for example
}
```

I did this to avoid having to convert the object to map everytime I want to access some attribute of the object and if I were to write a line of code for each attribute of my object I would rather make it efficient.

Note that in some cases you *will need/have* a ".toMap" or at least a ".toJson" function for your object, in which case your code would be smaller if you just reuse those functions, but you'll still lose that tiny performance difference.